# How to use dotTrace Performance Profiling while launching the WPF application it self

Tags: wpf, performance, user-interface, dottrace

Am working on WPF application. It is taking lot of time to launch the application so one of my client raised performance issue. To solve/identify the issue what is the best solution ? and am using dotTrace profiler to identify the issue but while launching how can I attach process to application ?.

Comment: Please include your code in the question. This will make the question much easier for people to effectively answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch your application under dotTrace - it's a standard way to profile an app. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Starting_Local_Profiling_Session.html